# telerik radgrid last column(s) gets cut off

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I'm getting last columns in radgrid cut off. The grid is scrollable and sum of column widths is definitely wider than given width. The cut columns are of course in the page source. there is 18 columns like the one below. Why could it be? Thank you! 
    `<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="rg" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true"
        AllowFilteringByColumn="true" Skin="Telerik" Width="1000px" AllowPaging="true"
        PageSize="20" OnNeedDataSource="needData">
        <ClientSettings Scrolling-FrozenColumnsCount="2" Scrolling-SaveScrollPosition="true"
            Scrolling-UseStaticHeaders="true" Scrolling-AllowScroll="true" />
 <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
        <MasterTableView Width="100%" TableLayout="Fixed" >
   <PagerStyle Position="TopAndBottom" Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced" AlwaysVisible="true" />
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="report_number" HeaderText="Report #" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true" ShowSortIcon="false"/>`

Comment: Please post the screenshot.

Comment: apparently I can't, I don't have reputation. I'll try to describe: the grid has both scrollbars, if I scroll all the way to the right I don't see the last column. the best I could get was one or two letters of the header, the rest is not visible.

Comment: Upload the screenshot somewhere on the web and post a link to it :)

Answer (score 1):

resolved like this: first, doctype issue. removing "transitional" part from the declaration solved cutting the column in the middle. adding a fake column with headertext="" and no data after the last I need forced the last column with data to show.

just in case: MasterTableView width=101% did not help (found this someplace else)